# How can I make a callback to a class through my homepage when it is already contextualised through my main screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

To elaborate, how do I clear tasks list in TaskData through a callback from TaskScreen? I'm finding it a bit difficult to describe but please refer to the comments in the code it'll be easier to understand.

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => TaskData(),
      child: MaterialApp(,
          home: TaskScreen()),
    );
  }
```

**TaskData**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todo/models/task.dart';

class TaskData extends ChangeNotifier {
 TaskData();
 List<Task> tasks = [
   Task(name: 'Doodh le', time: null, date: null),
   Task(name: 'Anda le', time: null, date: null),
 ];

//function to clear tasks that I want to callback
 void clearTasks(List tasks) {
   tasks.clear();
   notifyListeners();
 }
}
```

**TaskScreen**

```
class TaskScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TaskScreenState createState() => _TaskScreenState();
}

class _TaskScreenState extends State<TaskScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Text('Delete all tasks'),
        onPressed: () {
          //callback to clear tasks
        },
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Consumer<TaskData>` or `Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false ).clearTasks`?

Comment: @Asadhameed No I haven't tried this. Can you elaborate on this? Post this as an answer.

Comment: See the answer by @chunhunghan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You can use  `Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false).clearTasks();` 
Step 2: You do not need parameter in `clearTasks()`

```
void clearTasks() {
    _tasks.clear();
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class TaskScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TaskScreenState createState() => _TaskScreenState();
}

class _TaskScreenState extends State<TaskScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        Consumer<TaskData>(builder: (context, taskData, child) {
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: taskData.tasks.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                      elevation: 3,
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(taskData.tasks[index].name),
                      ),
                    )),
          );
        }),
        Center(
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text('Delete all tasks'),
            onPressed: () {
              Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false).clearTasks();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}

class Task {
  String name;
  DateTime time;
  DateTime date;

  Task({this.name, this.time, this.date});
}

class TaskData extends ChangeNotifier {
  TaskData();
  List<Task> _tasks = [
    Task(name: 'Doodh le', time: null, date: null),
    Task(name: 'Anda le', time: null, date: null),
  ];

  UnmodifiableListView<Task> get tasks => UnmodifiableListView(_tasks);

//function to clear tasks that I want to callback
  void clearTasks() {
    _tasks.clear();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => TaskData(),
      child: MaterialApp(home: TaskScreen()),
    );
  }
}
```